# Strange behaviour in R when using predict

Tags: r

I typed the following command in R:

```
predict(lm.fit, data.frame(lstat = (c(5,10,15))), interval = "confidence")
```

where lm.fit is a linear regression fit. I am using the Boston dataset. The output I am expecting is

```
fit lwr upr
1 29.80 29.01 30.60
2 25.05 24.47 25.63
3 20.30 19.73 20.87
```

instead I am getting the following output:

```
           fit        lwr        upr
1   29.8225951 29.0252990 30.6198912
2   25.8703898 25.2652456 26.4755340
3   30.7251420 29.8734766 31.5768074
4   31.7606958 30.8435939 32.6777976
5   29.4900778 28.7120765 30.2680791
6   29.6040837 28.8195155 30.3886520
7   22.7447274 22.2015728 23.2878820
8   16.3603958 15.6261142 17.0946773
9    6.1188637  4.6964329  7.5412945
10  18.3079969 17.6682721 18.9477218
11  15.1253316 14.3211061 15.9295571
12  21.9466860 21.4017704 22.4916015
13  19.6285655 19.0379343 20.2191967
14  26.7064332 26.0688676 27.3439989
15  24.8063345 24.2337154 25.3789536
16  26.5069229 25.8775896 27.1362562
17  28.3025161 27.5895545 29.0154778
18  20.6166169 20.0524476 21.1807861
19  23.4477639 22.8999502 23.9955777
20  23.8372842 23.2844310 24.3901373
21  14.5838035 13.7470635 15.4205434
22  21.4146583 20.8644307 21.9648859
...

'newdata' had 3 rows but variables found have 506 rows
```

This goes on for another few hundred lines. I am confused because I am following the book "An introduction to statistical learning with applications in R" exactly.

> What is going on?

Comment: How did you fit the model? (I'm assuming `MASS::Boston`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to do some guessing here but it seems that you fitted your model something like this:

```r
lm.fit <- lm(MASS::Boston$medv ~ MASS::Boston$lstat)
```

That is, specifying your data object in the formula. This way, `predict` doesn't recognize the `lstat` variable in the data frame you pass to it because it expects `MASS::Boston$lstat` which it finds in the global environment and happily uses (well, maybe not so happily, it does issue a warning). So you get the same result as when calling `predict(lm.fit, interval='confidence')`. The solution is simple, just don't specify your model object in the formula and supply it to `lm` using the `data` argument:

```r
lm.fit <- lm(medv ~ lstat, MASS::Boston)
```

And now you will get your expected result:

```r
predict(lm.fit, data.frame(lstat = (c(5,10,15))), interval = "confidence")
       fit      lwr      upr
1 29.80359 29.00741 30.59978
2 25.05335 24.47413 25.63256
3 20.30310 19.73159 20.87461
```